# What does "Primary constructor body not allowed" mean?

Tags: c#

I am attempting to compile and run this C# program in Terminal:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


public class largestNumber
{
    public static void Main(string[] args);
    {
        int UserNumber1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine("Enter a number:"));
        int UserNumber2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine("Enter a second number:"));
        int UserNumber3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine("Enter a third number:"));

        Console.WriteLine("Your numbers were, " + UserNumber1 + ", " + UserNumber2 + ", and " + UserNumber3);
    }
}
```

however, when I do so, this error comes up:

```
Number.cs(11,2): error CS9010: Primary constructor body is not allowed
```

Can someone explain what the error is referring to?

Comment: `public static void Main(string[] args);` - look at the end of the line. Fix the simple typographical error.

Comment: Although it is mildly interesting, perhaps, to expand on what the compiler means by a "Primary constructor body" (or if it is just fallout of the bad syntax).

Comment: Probably worth noting that primary constructors are a C# 6 thing so many people may not know what they are yet.

Comment: So what are they exactly? Or is this something to take to a different question altogether?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple problems with your app:

- Method implementations do not take a `;` at the end.
- `Console.ReadLine` does not take any arguments. Its only purpose is to read the console, so you should use `Console.WriteLine` to ask your questions like "Enter a number".
- You should wrap your class in a namespace (Which is usually named like your .csproj project)

And please follow C# conventions, with class names as PascalCase and variables as camelCase. When you share your code, it's easier for other developers to read and understand it.

So it should look like this:

```
using System;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class LargestNumber
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
            int userNumber1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a second number:");
            int userNumber2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a third number:");
            int userNumber3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Your numbers were, " + userNumber1 + ", " + userNumber2 + ", and " + userNumber3);
        }
    }
}
```

Please note I removed some of your useless `using` statements.

You should also rename your file `Number.cs` to `LargestNumber.cs`, you usually want your file to have the same name as your class.

---

Also, I'm not getting the same compilation error as you, even by copy-pasting your code.

Under VS2015 I have "Non-abstract and non-extern method must declare a body" (caused by the extra semi-colon) and "Method ReadLine has 0 parameter(s) but is invoked with 1 argument(s)". The error you're getting may be caused by syntax errors somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Thank you for the timely response! I was a little confused as to how WriteLine and ReadLine should work, so thanks for clearing that up. For future reference, was that error caused by the ';' after the Main method?

Comment: I can't repro your error on my VS2015 (I detailed those I got after the answer), and Googling the error message/error ID don't yield anything. So it's possible it was caused by a combination of factors.

Comment: Okay, I was using MonoDevelop on OS X if that means anything. Anyways, it's fixed now.

Comment: Primary constructors were a proposed feature for c#6 that was later removed. Perhaps monodevelop added a message specific to this case? It could be detecting the incorrect syntax as a parameterless primary constructor. Just a guess though...