# "Primary Constructor Body Is Not Allowed" Error

Tags: c#, error-handling

I am getting an error in my code "Primary Constructor Body Is Not Allowed", and can't seem to find a way to fix it. The error occurred because I created a new public method, I have also tried using private and protected methods, but the error was still present. There is someone else on here that asked the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31757953/what-does-primary-constructor-body-not-allowed-mean). The answer that the particular person got leads me to believe that it may be specific to OS X.
Here is my code:

```
        string txt = WordBank ();

        string[] words = Moduel.TextToArray("Text.txt");
        string compWord = Moduel.Random (words);    
        Console.WriteLine ("I have chosen a random word, try to guess it one letter at a time");
    }

    public static void WordBank ();
    {
        string txt;

        Console.WriteLine ("Would you like to " +
            "(A) choose 4 letter words " +
            "(B) choose 5 letter words " +
            "(C) choose 6 letter words " +
            "(E) choose 7 lette r words or more?" +
            "(F) all words?");

        string input = Console.ReadLine ();
        if (input = "A")
            txt = "4 Letter Words.txt";
        else if (input = "B")
            txt = "5 Letter Words.txt";
        else if (input = "C")
            txt = "6 Letter Words.txt";
        else if (input = "E")
            txt = "7 Letters or More.txt";
        else if (input = "F")
            txt = "All Words.txt";
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You haven't chosen a valid option, please try again");
            Main();
        }
        return txt;
    }
}
```

}

and here is a picture of the error.
[Error Message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rG1h.png)

Comment: Why is it `public static *void* WordBank` when you want to return a `string`?

Comment: appreciate the upvoter for giving +1 to this basic error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error is in

> public static void WordBank ();

Just remove semicolon from this line

> public static void WordBank ()

And your function returned a string value so change function's definition  to

> public static string WordBank ()

Comment: what about a method void method returning a string value?

Answer (score 3):

`public static void WordBank ();` Remove the trailing `;` in this line. and also make the return type to `string` if you have to return a string from the function.

So your method signature will be like the following:

```
public static string WordBank ()
    {
        string txt;
        //Rest of code comes here
        return txt;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently you have `;` after your method declaration:

```
public static void WordBank ();
{
    // code in your method
}
```

Having semicolon after method declaration is effectively the same like having an empty method body, so in your case the code is the same as

```
public static void WordBank ()
{
}
{
    // code in your method
}
```

which is incorrect.

In order to fix the issue remove the `;` after the method name:

```
public static void WordBank ()
{
    // code in your method
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are certainly number of errors in you code.

1. `string txt = WordBank ();` where as your function does not return
   anything `public static void WordBank ();` its void.
2. your code to declare a function `public static void WordBank ();` is wrong since you need to remove the `;` at the end.
3. inside the function you states `return txt;` which is not right until your function actually returns something

and thus your code should be

```
public static string WordBank()
{
    return "SomeString"; // in your case txt
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your fast responses, the semicolon was the issue (feel really stupid now :P).