# C# User input that shows the difference needed to get to certain number

Tags: c#

I started with C# and bit of a newbie at it, need some advice and guidance

I'm busy with an C# exercise that does the following

Ask number input (not greater than 20)
output user input (lets say 8 was user input) and show the difference needed to get to 20 (12)
Also show an error message when user enters 20 (Sorry that is not allowed)

I have looked into different solutions online but none actually work and started from scratch. here is how far I have gotten.

```
public class LessThan20
{
  public static void Main();
{
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number less than 5:");
string numberInput = Console.ReadLine();
public string NumberInput { get => numberInput; set => numberInput = value; }

    (Mathf.Abs(numberInput) >= 20)
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at C# [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) and what they do and why `NumberInput` isn't correct where it is. Then look at basic variables, variable types, Parsing to other types and logic operators.

Comment: When learning to code, it's best to always start from scratch, so that you're teaching yourself to do more than search for and copy someone else's code.  You want to train your brain to think things through logically.  If you get stuck on a specific topic or technique, then ask for help on that technique.  But it smells here like you may need to rewind and start over with some 'beginning C#' primers?

Comment: *"I started with C# and bit of a newbie at it, need some advice and guidance"* - you need a teacher or good book. What you attempting to do is clearly not doable .. yet. The answers below help you to complete exercise, but you should be rather learning the basics: structure of code and how to understand compiler errors. The latter is actually very easy, just copy error text and google for it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31757953/1997232) is duplicate of error.

Comment: Hey guys, I'm use to python and wanted to learn something else as well, thanks for all the info given here. I will definitely check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could work, I don't know how much it helps though.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number less than 20: ");
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

    if(!int.TryParse(userInput, out int number))
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number between 0 and 20");
    else if(number > 0 && number < 20)
    {
        int result = 20 - number;
        Console.WriteLine($"Difference of {result} is needed to get to 20.");
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number greater than 0 and smaller than 20");
}
```

Perhaps try looking up some stuff about if statements, variables, variable types, and other basics. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to capture number from 0-19 and rest of value will return error message , example :  20 , A , b , c , symbol etc ....you code will be something like this....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


        while (true)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter number from range 0-19 ");
            string numberInput = Console.ReadLine();
            int IntNumberInput = 0;

            try {
                IntNumberInput = System.Convert.ToInt32(numberInput);


                if (IntNumberInput >= 0 && IntNumberInput <= 19)
                {
                    int CalculationResult = 20 - IntNumberInput;
                    Console.WriteLine("You enter number from range 0-19 , Result was " + CalculationResult.ToString());
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Environment.Exit(0);

                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("Sorry that is not allowed , Please enter number from range 0-19"); }


            }



    }
```

Comment: Thanks man, I checked out your version and Its very cool! thanks for your reply :D